# How to replace a VALUE of Particular KEY inside Mutable Map in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mutable

I have a response from the api where I want to replace the VALUE of a particular KEY. How to do it

```
MutableMap<String!, String!>
```

> {sendbird_call={"user_id":"91990000000","push_sound":"default","is_voip":true,"push_alert":"","client_id":"xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx","command":{"sequence_number":2,"payload":{"sdp":"sdpppppp","call_id":"xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxx",**"peer_connection_id":null**},"delivery_info":{"type":"push"},"message_id":"xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xx-xxxx","cmd":"SGNL","type":"offer","call_type":"direct_call","version":1},"receiver_type":"client"},
> message=}

From the above response I need to change the value of **peer_connection_id** from **null** to **""**

```
var msgData = JSONObject(receivedMap["sendbird_call"])
  if (msgData.has("command")) {
     val dataCommand: JSONObject = msgData.getJSONObject("command")
        if (dataCommand.has("payload")) {
           val dataPay: JSONObject = dataCommand.getJSONObject("payload")
              if (dataPay.has("peer_connection_id")) {
                 if(dataPay.getString("peer_connection_id").equals(null)){
                    dataPay.put("peer_connection_id","")
                 }
              }
        }
  }
```

Any advice or help

With answer of IR42

```
 private fun replacePeerID(receivedMap: Map<String, String>): Map<String, String> {

    var msgData = JSONObject(receivedMap["sendbird_call"])

    msgData.optJSONObject("command")
        ?.optJSONObject("payload")
        ?.let {
            if (it.has("peer_connection_id") && it.opt("peer_connection_id") == null) {
                it.put("peer_connection_id", "")
            }
        }

    return receivedMap
}
```

Comment: Does your supplied code not work? If not, what happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: you can put a simple null check or a empty check on String `TextUtils.isEmpty(dataPay.getString("peer_connection_id"))` .

Comment: @JensV Yes not working return the same. Need to return the same mutablemap obj with only one change is to replace null with "" for the KEY peer_connection_id

Comment: @ADM yes we can check null or empty if we parse it to use on our UI, but here I need to pass this mutablemap obj to a nullable function of Sendbird library (which i used for call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private fun replacePeerID(receivedMap: Map<String, String>): Map<String, String> {
    val msgData = JSONObject(receivedMap["sendbird_call"] ?: "{}")
    return msgData.optJSONObject("command")
        ?.optJSONObject("payload")
        .let { payloadObject ->
            if (payloadObject != null &&
                payloadObject.has("peer_connection_id") &&
                payloadObject.opt("peer_connection_id") == JSONObject.NULL
            ) {
                payloadObject.put("peer_connection_id", "")
                receivedMap + ("sendbird_call" to msgData.toString())
            } else {
                receivedMap
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: How to form this as a function which return as mutablemap after replace?. I have edited my question with your answer.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter peerConnectionId